# Viewing an object

Tags: javascript, object

I am learning JS and after fiddling around with adding elements etc I tried to do an alert() with the object but instead got this error: `[object htmltableelement]`
so I then tried:

```
alert(t.toString());
```

and got the same error... how can I see the contents of the object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use firebug:

```
console.log(t);
```

or you can use innerHTML;

```
alert(t.innerHTML);
```

Comment: `innerHTML` is a property only of HTML DOM nodes. It's possible that his object is a DOM node, but by no means guaranteed; at the very least, this needs noting.

Comment: @Tomalak you are right, since @Ryan mentioned the message was `htmltableelement` then we can fairly say that t is an HTML DOM Node. So innerHTML will apply to this variable

Comment: That's great, but he should be made aware that this is not a _general_ solution for printing object contents, since he is "learning JS".

Answer (score 2):

The way I normally do this is by using FireBug firefox add-on.
Add a break point in  your JavaScript then you can view any object and all its keys/values.

Comment: Yes Chrome also has 'developer tools'   press `control + shift + i` .  This is assuming you just want to know the value for debuging.  Once  you open the tools click on the SCRIPTS tab then insert a Break Point on the line of code you want to inspect, then on the right hand side of the screen you can see 'watch variables' values

Comment: Ok, did that and there is wayyyy too much details there... kinda info overload.. :(

Comment: oops, was looking in scope variables... will check again

Comment: I dont have "watch variables" but I do have "watch expressions" and that is blank...

Comment: so when you code hits the break point.  You right click your variable and press "add to watch" and it wil show up under watch expressions.  Learning to use Dev Tools will be a very usful skill to have as it has a ton of other useful features for debuging JS, HTML, CSS, AJAX etc . see http://www.sagarganatra.com/2011/05/javascript-debugging-with-chrome.html

Answer (score 1):

See everything:

```
for(var key in t)
  alert('key:' + key + ', value: ' + t[key]);
```

You may want to replace alert with console to avoid 100s of alerts

Answer (score 1):

```
function domObjectToString(domObject){   
    if(typeof(domObject) ==='object'){    
        var divElement = document.createElement('div') ;    
        divElement.appendChild(domObject);    
        return divElement.innerHTML;    
    }else{     
        return domObject.toString();     
    }
}
```

---- steps follow -----
1.  check the domObject Type [object]
2. If Object than
     a. Create an "Div" element
     b. append DomObject To It
     c. get The innerHTML of the "div" it Gives The String
3. If Not an Object than convert to String and return it .

Answer (score 0):

That is not an error. That is the default string representation of an object.

Either iterate through the object's properties and output them one by one, or use a proper debugging tool like [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) that'll give you the ability to *really* examine your variables.

Comment: @Ryan: Chrome has [its own debugging tools](http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/), but even if it didn't would it be that much of a problem for you to use Firefox + Firebug for this particular purpose? IE also has an equivalent set of tools...

Comment: FF is kinda slow and hogs my laptop at times, so I am kind of stuck onto Chrome for a while now

Comment: Then use the Chrome debugging tools.